# PDF Buttons missing when I save in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-acrobat, button

I created a map in Illustrator CS6 which I exported to pdf. Using Acrobat 11.0.23 I created buttons which show information when the mouse hovers over the button area. If I reopen the PDF in Illustrator CS6 to change something (like the color of an area)and save it again, all the button functions are lost. Is there a method to preserve buttons made in Acrobat when saving in CS6?

Answer (score 3):

Illustrator CS6 has no interactivity functions. When you open the PDF with Illustrator it does not understand *any* of the interactivity. So, it ignores/dumps that code. It's non-native code to the application (AI) and can't translate the Acrobat code to AI code because there's no matching functionality.

There's no method I am aware of to get Illustrator CS6 to understand, maintain, and support Acrobat 11 interactive settings.

Answer (score 0):

For interactivity design and basic graphic design, **InDesign** is a *better* choice, allows for your interactivity design to be native to your source files, and of course supports *direct placing* of Illustrator files as well, so you can in fact use a hybrid workflow that should get you everything you need, *albeit true* that you ***won't*** be *retaining* what you did in Acrobat, you will *re-create* it **once**, and then it'll be part of your native InDesign source file from therein.

This is preferable as it allows easy one-to-many iteration and publishing.